# How can I get color space from a CGContext?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-graphics, cgcontext

I want to create a bitmap `CGContext` with the same color space as an existing `CGContext`.
How can I get the `UIColor` space of a `CGContext`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `CGBitmapContextGetColorSpace` to get the colour space of a given bitmap context,
but if you're talking about a general context then the question isn't well defined because CGContexts have two colour spaces: stroke and fill.

Comment: How can I get color space for stroke or fill?
What I want is to create a bitmap context for offline drawing, and then draw the bitmap context to current context.
And I don't use CGLayer, because I don't want to cache it.

Comment: I don't think you can. What's the worst that could happen if you don't set the colour space? p.s. Your colour space is probably DeviceRGB.